# How do I turn off warning messages in httpclient for log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, httpclient

I have the following in my log4j file

```
#set httpclient debug levels
log4j.logger.org.apache.component=ERROR,stdout 
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=ERROR,stdout 
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=ERROR,stdout
```

but I'm still getting warnings when I run my httpclient code... am I missing something?
thanks!

```
WARN [pool-1-thread-69] (ResponseProcessCookies.java:126) - Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: webtb_state][value: method%3Dsu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ResponseProcessCookies`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/protocol/ResponseProcessCookies.html) is in the `org.apache.http.client.protocol` package, which you don't seem to have covered. Perhaps go for `org.apache.http.client`?

(You may also need to set additivity to false; it's been a while since I've configured log4j.)